# Why is my full view model not being serialized by ApiController?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following type hierarchy for `ClientIndexModel`:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public virtual IDictionary<string, SelectList> SelectListDictionary
    {
        get
        {
            var props = GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(SelectList));
            return props.ToDictionary(prop => prop.Name, prop => (SelectList)prop.GetValue(this, null));
        }
    }
}
public class IndexModel<TIndexItem, TEntity> : ViewModel where TIndexItem : ViewModel where TEntity : new()
{
    public List<TIndexItem> Items { get; private set; }
}
public class ClientIndexModel: IndexModel<ClientIndexItem, Client>
{
}
```

I instantiate in and return a `ClientIndexModel` from an ApiController as follows:

```
public ClientIndexModel Get()
{
    var model = new ClientIndexModel();
    return model;
}
```

If I inspect `model` with a breakpoint on the `return model;` line, the `Items` property is present, with a count of 0. Yet the JSON returned from this action only has the `SelectListDictionary` property and no `Items` property. Why could this be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Items` property has a private setter. Properties with private setters are intentionally omitted from serialization as it makes no sense to serialize them because they can never be deserialized back as their values cannot be modified from the outside. So you should either completely remove the setter (as you have done for the `SelectListDictionary` property), make it public or write a custom formatter using some custom serializer that is capable of serializing properties with private setters.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks. That setter is a throwback from when my index models were all strictly reinforced display only. Shouldn't have still been there, but I would never have guessed it stops serialization.